# Is there a way to stop Visual Studio 2010 from auto-generating CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio and anytime I touch a cell in a table it generates CSS. I have the style-application mode set to manual. Is there any other way to turn this off?

Comment: Edit in code mode, not design mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will add styles if you do things like, resizing tables and things like that. If you don't do it, it should not add styles. Editing in code mode and not design mode will also help.